# How to check for a null value in remoting call

Tags: javascript-remoting

I have the following code which checks for an ID and then calls a function on retrieve in the remoting call in salesforce. Now when the record is retreived and it is null then how to handle it. I mean the case when record.retrieve is successful but the record is null in that case the error is not thrown. bewlow is my code

```
        if(objModel){
              objModel.retrieve({ where: { Id: { eq: urlObject.aid}} }, loadRecordType);
          }
      }

      function loadRecordType(error,records,event){
            if(err){

   }
```

In above function how can I check that the records given are null?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a "null record," so I presume you meant to say "when no records are returned," which looks like:

```
if(error) {
    display(error)
} else if(records.length) {
    render(records)
} else {
    // no records found, but no error occurred
}
```